# getting value from cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting value from cloud firestore using the code below

```
dbManager = admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

this.dbManager.collection("test").doc("myTest").get().then( async test=> {
    console.log("test---------------->",test);
    console.log("test---------------->",test._fieldsProto['tests']);
    console.log("test---data------------->",test.data()['tests'].values);
});
```

and the value I get when I use `test.data()['tests']` is

```
{ values: 
   [ { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' },
     { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' } ] }
```

How do I get values from this? When I try with foreach like `test.data()['tests'].array.forEach` it is not working.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what your actual document looks like. Can you post a screenshot of the `myTest` document as it shows in the [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/)?

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Do you get wrong output, or none at all, or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test.data()['tests']` doesn't return an array, it returns a map `{values: []}`.

What you need to do is first get `values` and then loop over the array:

```
test.data()['tests'].values.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

Replace the `console.log()` with whatever you wanna do with all the entries.